# No se solucionar los errores que me indica Google developers pagespeed cache

Tags: wordpress, aplicación-web, cache

Estoy trabajando en una página web y ya está subida al hosting (pero como tengo que arreglar alguna cosilla aún, he cerrado el acceso). El tema es que lo abrí un momento para ver que me decía google en sus herramientas de velocidad de carga de una web, y me han salido unos errores que no he sabido solucionar. Es la primera vez que hago un proyecto web.

Este es uno de los errores que me da pero la verdad que esto nunca lo había escuchado y aunque he leído información al respecto, no entiendo como arreglarlo :(

> Especificar caché de navegador
>   Establecer una fecha de caducidad o una edad máxima en las cabeceras HTTP de los recursos estáticos indica al navegador que cargue los recursos descargados previamente del disco local en lugar de hacerlo a través de la red.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especificar la cache es basicamente decirle al navegador por cuanto tiempo debe mantener los archivos (css, imagenes, javascript,  etc) almacenados en su cache antes de ser borrados o actualizados.

Debes crear o editar el archivo .htaccess con un contenido similar a lo siguiente

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
</IfModule>
```

Puedes especificar dias (Days), meses (Months) y años (Years).

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía como hacerlo. Me sale un warning con dos enlaces externos en lo de la caché, pero ahora que se donde he de modificarlo, lo que es etc, podré buscar una solución para ello. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: El mod expires debera estar activo en tu servidor apache, y la respuesta funcionara si el servidor web es Apache. Si el servidor es Nginx o IIE, deberas realizarlo de otra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendable este sitio para la solución de cada item de Google : https://varvy.com/ , este tema es toda una ciencia.